# How create a mdl checkbox element

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, element

By [getmdl.io](http://getmdl.io), a checkbox element is:

```css
#d{
padding:20px
```

```html
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.deep_purple-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="d">
<label for="chkbox1" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
 <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
 <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

and i try to add this element with js

```js
function addCB(){
  var cb = document.createElement('div');
  cb.innerHTML = `<label for="chkbox1" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
 <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
 <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>`;
  document.getElementById('d').appendChild(cb);
}
```

```css
#d{
padding:20px
```

```html
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.deep_purple-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="d">
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect " onClick="addCB()">Add checkbox</button>
```

but the design doesn't work, idk why, can anyone help me?

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a problem description. Please explain what the code is expected to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the effect you wanted by using the following two additional lines:

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom('MaterialCheckbox');
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```

Here is some information about [componentHandler](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works).

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/owPzMo).

Answer (score 1):

FYI MDL is deprecated for MDC-Web, however if you must use it, you get at it like any other checkbox, namely, document.getElementByID("checkbox1").checked which returns a boolean.